# Declaring and using an array of size n vs declaring and using n variables

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, declaration

I was solving a question on codeforces, where I submitted two solutions: [A](https://codeforces.com/contest/1119/submission/67403611) and [B](https://codeforces.com/contest/1119/submission/67403663).

The only difference that I want you all to see, is that in A, I had declared an array of size *n* and then ran a loop for inserting elements in that array. In the second submission, B, I didn't declare any array, and did variable declaration and insertion on the go.

Therefore, I had expected a reduction in both run time, and memory used. The memory used went down to 0 KB, but the run time increased. That was not expected at all!

The difference, in my opinion, might have come due to nature of memory allocated (maybe). The array has contiguous memory, which might have been easier to allocate, than allocating memory to variables.

Or it might be that the scope of the variable ends with the end of one loop iteration, which might require some cleaning.

So, all in all, I'm not very sure what is causing the difference in run time. I hope there is some logical explanation behind this behaviour.

---

**A:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;
#define f(i,s,n) for(int i=s;i<n;i++)
typedef long long ll ;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0) ;
    cin.tie(0) ;
    cout.tie(0) ;
    int n;cin>>n;
    int arr[n];f(i,0,n) cin>>arr[i] ;
    ll rem = 0 ;
    ll ans = 0 ;
    f(i,0,n)
    {
        ll a = arr[i] ;
        ll remTr = min(rem,a/2) ;
        ans+=remTr+(a-2*remTr)/3 ;
        rem = rem-remTr+(a-2*remTr)%3 ;
    }
    cout<<ans<<"\n" ;
    return 0;
}
```

**B:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;
#define f(i,s,n) for(int i=s;i<n;i++)
typedef long long ll ;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0) ;
    cin.tie(0) ;
    cout.tie(0) ;
    int n;cin>>n;
    // int arr[n];f(i,0,n) cin>>arr[i] ;// This is deleted
    ll rem = 0 ;
    ll ans = 0 ;
    f(i,0,n)
    {
        ll a;cin>>a ;//This is added
        ll remTr = min(rem,a/2) ;
        ans+=remTr+(a-2*remTr)/3 ;
        rem = rem-remTr+(a-2*remTr)%3 ;
    }
    cout<<ans<<"\n" ;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Indeed, declaration seems to be the problem. I shifted the declaration out of the loop, and did insertion on the same variable. That took the exact time, like that of the first submission (A). Here is the [third submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1119/submission/67404092).

Nevertheless, I would still like to thoroughly understand what is going on under the hood.

---

**EDIT:** I know this is not standard C++, because this is not production code, and was never meant to be. Please don't point out standardization, because the way the code is written, is intentional, and serves the purpose for which it was written.

Nevertheless, any comments that actually answer the question are welcome.

Comment: Could be your compiler is reallocating a new variable inside the loop each time, and that is slowing you down. But most compilers now days should optimize that, so I don't really know for sure.

Comment: This program is more than likely limited by the time the input operations take, everything else will be pretty much irrelevant. Moving the declaration of `a` outside the loop makes zero difference. The generated code is 100% the same, see https://godbolt.org/z/V453Qh. I'd guess that the site's benchmaking is just bad. None of this should make any difference. Try submitting the same code, but change some variable names, and see whether the timing results will match.

Comment: `#define f(i,s,n) for(int i=s;i<n;i++); typedef long long ll ;` -- Please don't do this.  And this: `int n;cin>>n;int arr[n]` is not valid C++.

Comment: Your "helper" macros succeed in making the code unreadable to most humans.   Also, your usage of `int arr[n]` in case A is invalid, since variable length arrays are not part of standard C++.    At best, you are using a compiler-specific, non-standard, extension - which will be rejected by a number of compilers.

Comment: @walnut Thanks but this is competitive programming, which doesn't require readabily,  but speed to implement. Sorry if it is unreadable, but the question specifically highlights the problem, and thus it was not required to read any other part of the code in order to answer the question. It is just for completion purposes.

Comment: @Mooncrater My first comment addresses the performance (non-)issue.

Comment: @walnut Yes yes. Great suggestions! Thank you. The `#define` saves a lot of time, and since the code is less, it saves from basic bugs too. But the idea of "if you know the upper limit to size, why declare a variable array", and "`#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is as messy as it gets", are great saviours.

Comment: A general hint: If you want to learn about effects of one statement vs. another statement, your way of concurrent solutions for competitive programming is a bit ... tedious and unprecise. If you really want to puzzle this out, then I recommend comparison of minimal MCVEs on [Compiler Explorer](http://www.godbolt.org).

Comment: @Mooncrater -- *and thus it was not required to read any other part of the code in order to answer the question* -- Then how was one to figure out what `ll` or `f()` is?  Wouldn't they need to read the other parts of the code?  Second, there is no "competition" here on Stack Overflow -- you could have taken the time to make the code readable and post it.